# Android parsing json

Tags: android, json

Im getting problems with parsing Json.
my json response.

```
 {
  "Persons": [
      {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "William",
          "image": "http://www.images-image2312321356.jpg",
          "colors": [
              "White",
              "Red",
              "Green"
          ]
      },
        {...}
```

Im trying this. but it causes a compile error

```
 public void onResponse(JSONObject responseObject) {
                    try {
                JSONArray rs = responseObject.getJSONArray("Persons"); 

                        for (int i = 0; i <  rs.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                final JSONObject c = rs.getJSONObject(i);
                               String name = c.getString("name");
                               items.add(name);
                               ));

                            }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Any idea? Im using volley

Comment: No, we don't have an idea because you have not provided your code, your exception (if any), or what you are trying to parse out of that JSON.

Comment: Missing a semicolon `c.getString("name")`. Maybe a typo `itemsLenght`. Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: I added a bit of code

Comment: Yes, it has been a problem to copy, but that is not the error.

Comment: Where does the `));` come from after `items.add`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject responseObject) {

        JSONArray rs = responseObject.getJSONArray("Persons");
        if (rs != null || rs.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rs.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject obj = rs.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = obj.getString("id");
                String name = obj.getString("name");
                String img = obj.getString("image");

                JSONArray colors = obj.getJSONArray("colors");
                for (int ii = 0; ii < colors.length(); ii++) {
                    String color = colors.getString(ii);
                    colors.add(color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```